# ограничение даты для столбца

Tags: sql, sql-server

надо создать столбец
Дата проведения (Date).

- Не может содержать null-значения.
- Не может быть больше текущей даты.

пытаюсь сделать вот так

```
ALTER TABLE Lectures
ADD [Date] DATE NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT CHK_ColumnD_CurD
CHECK([Date] <= CURRENT_DATE);
GO
```

ошибка:

> CURDATE не является известным имя встроенной функции.

Comment: CHECK-ограничение не может быть динамическим и/или использовать недетерминированные выражения. Используйте триггерную логику.

Comment: Ну и неплохо бы знать, с чем работаете... MySQL <> SQL Server (MS SQL).

Comment: MySQL, в приложении microsoft SQL server tools. а без триггерной возможно? просто для  развития

Comment: *MySQL, в приложении microsoft SQL server tools.* Да ладно! Точно? Что возвращает `SELECT VERSION();`?

Comment: Сообщение 195, уровень 15, состояние 10, строка 2
VERSION не является известным имя встроенной функции.

Время выполнения: 2023-06-13T21:52:35.4735480+05:00

Comment: я учусь , на чем учат я не выбирал, просто учитель не отвечает на вопросы вне уроков. решил здесь спросить

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64)   Oct  8 2022 05:58:25   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19045: )

Comment: Ну таки не MySQL... В любом случае мимо триггера не проехать. Не, можно и другие варианты рассматривать - вставка хранимой процедурой вместо одиночного запроса, вставка значения пользовательской функции, а не встроенной... но всё это как минимум неразумно. И непременно на уровне процесса ввода, а не в структуре таблицы.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ, значит буду делать триггер